# net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT in dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I am doing a server side dart code using notepad++, I have already succeed in server side dart code using dart editor. But I the same think where I done with notepad++ done a error as net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT in dart in browser, Dart server side initialed by Command prompt is done, When I try to access 172....190 ,Bowser(dartium) said that above error!!!

server side code

```
main() {
  HttpServer.bind("172...", 4045).then((server) {
    server.listen((res) {
      res.response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "172.25.10.181");
      res.response.headers
          .add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
      res.response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
          'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      print('I am writing server side code');
    });
  });
}
```

Client side code

```
req = new HttpRequest();

  req.open('get', 'http://172...:4045');

  req.send(data);

  req.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) {
    if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
        (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0)) {
     print(req.responseText);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shameless copied from https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports

> Right Click on Chrome shortcut >> Properties >>

Then Append 
`--explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx` to shortcut target

**Example:**

> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local
>   Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666

Resource from  [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=7512620ef6d830c3&hl=en)

Comment: but the port number 4047 is coming, why not 4045?

Comment: I think if we create 4045 once, We need to destroy that port. But currently 4045 port is running, I am sure no other port is running.

Comment: I still have no idea ;-) I just googled your error message and found the answer. Never run into any such issue.

Comment: Summoned more knowledgeable people https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/TL6XmY8sSrE

Comment: ok thank you! how to create question on google 
Dart Web Development .

Comment: Click the red "New Topic" button. You might need to join first.

Answer (score 11):

### Here is a best way to deal with this issue.

> There some ports are reserved for specific protocols like 80 for HTTP
> and 22 for SSH etc. If you use that port for another kind of protocol
> you will face this error. In my case, I'm using 6000 port for my
> backend API server which was resolved. I just simply move 6000 port to
> 7789 all stuff working as expected. [Here are the list ports for
> specific protocols that you may not violate.](https://medium.com/@msinha2801/why-are-some-ports-considered-unsafe-restricted-c3c22d0596c0) You need to use port other then this for your specific work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in some versions of Chrome that prevents the given **--explicitly-allowed-ports** solution from working.  In that case, a **temporary** workaround would be:

1. Browse to chrome://flags/#network-service.
2. Set "Enable network service" to Disabled.
3. Restart Chrome.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732271/explicitly-allowed-ports-not-working-in-latest-google-chrome-v-72-0-3626-109)