# explicitly-allowed-ports not working in latest google chrome v. 72.0.3626.109

Tags: google-chrome, browser, port

We have few local sites with unsafe ports i.e. 100,101,102,103. Those were working fine on google chrome with explicitly-allowed-ports in the shortcut target. Suddenly they have stopped working for new update version of chrome v. 72.0.3626.109.
I am not able to find any solution to it. Even if I install the old version of chrome it gets updated to the new one. Can you please guide me what to do. I cant change the mapping of websites as there are limitations. Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was already found in the Canary branch:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916025

Temporary solution is to disable the "Enable Network Service" option in the chrome://flags settings

Comment: Yes it did work, Thanks for it !! any idea when it will be resolved?

Comment: @vickyshazad Unfortunately, I can't tell.

Comment: Why I cannot find that "Enable Network Service" setting? I'm using chrome 79.0.3945.88

Comment: @youkaichao The bug seems to be fixed. Have you tried using the --explicitly-allowed-port option?